# V look up multiple task names based on live dates

Tags: excel, indexing, vlookup

Hi and thank you in advance.

So I currently have a workbook which consists of two sheets. The first sheet is a project log and the second sheet is a live date tracker.

What I am looking to do is have a formula search through the live dates in my project log and return all the project names which fall between the two dates entered within my live date tacker.

So for instance, the key columns and cells are as follows:

```
'Live date tracker'!R4 = Start from date
'Live date tracker'!R5 = End date
'Project Log'!E:E equals Project names column
'Project Log'!L:L equals Project Live date column
```

The formula I am after would be a V look up/index something like below:

```
IF 'Project Log!L:L IS GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO 'Live date tracker'!R4 
AND 
IF 'Project Log!L:L IS LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO 'Live date tracker'!R5
```

Return ALL project Names which fall within these dates from 'Project Log!E:E.

I know that this formula will need indexing and will involve +/- cell reference as it will need to return cell values one by one in a list but I am unsure how to do this.

If someone can help, that will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use construct like below.

It is Array formula so it needs to be entered by pressing **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER** simultaneously. If committed correctly, Excel will wrap formula with braces {}.

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Project Log'!E:E,SMALL(IF('Project Log'!L:L>='Live date tracker'!$R$3,IF('Project Log'!L:L<='Live date tracker'!$R$4,ROW('Project Log'!L:L),"a")),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")`

And then copy down as much as you want!